# Can the loops in the definition of the fundamental group be considered injective?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

Let $\mathrm{С}$ be some class of topological spaces that includes at least all subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n $. Further we are in the category $\mathrm{С}_{*}$ (the category of point spaces; all continuous maps and homotopies preserve the chosen base points). We define $π'_1(X) $ as the set of homotopy classes of products of injective loops in $X$ with the operation $[a] \cdot [b] = [a \cdot b]$. We say that $\mathrm{D} \subset \mathrm{C}$ is essentially wide if for every $X \in \mathrm{C}$ there exists $Y \in \mathrm{D}$ such that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$.

Is there a $ D $ essentially wide subclass of $ C $ such that, for $ X \in D $

1. The operation is well defined, i.e. there always exist an injective loop homotopic to $a \cdot b$
2. The natural embedding of $π'_1 (X) \to π_1 (X)$ is an isomorphism.

We define $π''_1 (X)$ similarly, but with homotopies in the class of injective loops.

Is there a $ D $ essentially wide subclass of $ C $ such that, for $X \in D$

3. The operation is well defined, i.e. among the classes of injective homotopy there exists and is uniquely a class of loops freely homotopic $a \cdot b$
4. The natural embedding $π''_ 1(X) \to π_1 (X)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Isn't the answer obviously no with $X= S^1$ ? there are few (Homotopy class of) injective map $S^1 \to S^1$

Comment: @SimonHenry Really! It is necessary to extend the class of loops: this is the closure of the class of injective loops with respect to the exponentiation operation. I'll edit the question now, thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, if $X$ is a manifold dimension at least $3$ you can make any loop embedded by general position. You can similarly make homotopies go through embeddings if the dimension is at least $4$.

Comment: @skupers I'm interested arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb {R}^3$, not necessarily manifolds. Nevertheless, thanks, can you tell me where I can read about the fact you mentioned?

Comment: It's called the weak Whitney embedding theorem.  Wikipedia has a page with references.

Comment: Oh, the next obvious counter-example is a bunch of two circles. In fact, I meant that any words (i.e., elements of a free group) from injective loops are allowed. Now the question is formulated correctly.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you

Comment: Try a circle with a line sticking out at one point, with the base point on that line.

Comment: @WillSawin Indeed, thanks, but this is an insignificant problem in the sense of "let us pass to a homotopically equivalent space from this class of spaces". Now I will make changes to the question.

Comment: Should "essentially wide" be "homotopically wide"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber By using "substantially wide" I refer to the concept of a substantially wide subcategory. If you think it was worth adding "homotopically" to make it clear what morphisms we are talking about, then I will add it now.

Comment: What about passing from $X$ to $X \times \mathbb R^3$ or something?

Comment: @EschatumVerus I think you misunderstood my comment. In the question, you define the notion of *essentially wide* ("We say that $D\subset C$ is essentially wide if [...]") but you then use the phrase *homotopically wide* later on (e.g. "Is there a $D$ homotopically wide subclass [...]"), and indeed the word "essentially" never appears again. Do you really want to use both phrases? (And meanwhile you never use "substantially wide" except in your comment.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed, this is a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Griffiths Twin Cone](https://wildtopology.com/2014/06/28/the-griffiths-twin-cone/) (or double cone over the shrinking wedge of circles), $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, all injective loops are null-homotopic yet $\pi_1(G)$ is uncountable. Hence, injective loops don't generate any of the fundamental group. However, as @WillSawin mentions in the comments, it is possible that you can pass to $G\times C$ where $C$ is contractible. This should mean that your first question has a positive answer at least in the case where $C$ is the set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Specifically, given a space $X$ in your class of spaces, we can consider $Y=X\times [0,1]^2$ which is homotopy equivalent to $X$ by the projection and seems to be in the class you are interested in. Given a loop $\alpha:(S^1,\ast)\to (X,x_0)$, we can define paths $\beta_1,\beta_2:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ so that $\beta_1(t)=(t,0)$ and $\beta_2:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ is some other arc from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ that only meets $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ at its endpoints. Now consider the path $(\alpha(t),\beta_1(t))$ in $Y$ and follow it by the path $(\alpha(\ast),\beta_{2}(1-t))$. This concatenation defines an injective loop in $Y$ whose projection to $X$ is homotopic to $\alpha$. Hence, the injective loops in $Y$ generate the entire fundamental group of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see that as $\mathrm{C}$ should have been limited to only subspaces $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am very embarrassed for such a protracted bringing the question to the correct form, so I will accept this answer for now. But with the approval of the senior site contributors, I would like to edit the question again and leave the appropriate "disclaimer".

Comment: You are correct that it is a difficult open problem to decide if the fundamental group of every subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is torsion-free. It is still the case that the Griffiths twin-cone is an example of a Peano continuum in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where injective paths are unhelpful for understanding $\pi_1$. If you reformulate your question to something just about $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is probably best to just ask a new question.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no subspace $\mathbb{R}^3$ (1) homotopically equivalent to the Griffiths twin-con and (2) whose fundamental group is realized on injective loops?

Comment: No, i only meant what I said. I did not mean to say this stronger statement.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you and thought that you mean that you already know the answer to the question that I would like to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the new version of the question (where you allow to replace the space by a homotopy equivalent one) the answer is now "yes": just replace every $X$ by $\lvert\operatorname{Sing}(X)\rvert$. This is homotopy equivalent at least for $X$ a CW complex, and since $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$ is a Kan complex, every element in $\pi_1$ is represented by an embedded loop.

Comment: In the question, it is essential that we are talking about arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}^ n $, and not about CW complexes. For example, I think this question may be related to the existence of torsion in the fundamental group of the subset $\mathbb{R}^ 3$ (is this still an open problem for 2021?).